# Inner join 3 tabelas

Tags: php, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta.

```
$cmd = "SELECT ofertas.id, ofertas.titulo, ofertas.descricao,  ofertas.valor, ofertas.user_of, ofertas.categ, ofertas.local, ofertas.fav, favoritos.id_oferta

FROM ofertas
INNER JOIN favoritos
ON ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta
ORDER BY favoritos.id_user='$login_session'";
```

Na tabela dos favoritos eu tenho id, id_user, id_oferta(seja ela oferta simples ou oferta_pro)

Da maneira que esta, eu consigo fazer o que eu quero para a tabela ofertas. 
Só que eu tenho mais uma tabela chamada ofertas_pro que tambem tem os mesmos campos que a ofertas.

Queria algo do gênero:

```
    $cmd = "SELECT ofertas.id, ofertas.titulo, ofertas.descricao,   ofertas.valor, ofertas.user_of, ofertas.categ, ofertas.local, ofertas.fav, favoritos.id_oferta, ofertas_pro.id, ofertas_pro.titulo, ofertas_pro.descricao,   ofertas_pro.valor, ofertas_pro.user_of, ofertas_pro.categ, ofertas_pro.local, ofertas_pro.fav

FROM ofertas (e ofertas_pro)
INNER JOIN favoritos
ON ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta (e ofertas_pro.id=favoritos.id_oferta)
ORDER BY favoritos.id_user='$login_session'";
```

Deu para entender?

Está assim no momento:

```
$cmd = "SELECT o.id, o.titulo, o.descricao, o.valor, o.user_of, o.categ, o.local, o.fav, f.id_oferta
                    FROM ofertas AS o, favoritos AS f
                    WHERE o.id = f.id_oferta
                    ORDER BY f.id_user='$login_session'";



    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

//exibe os produtos 
        echo "<table style= width:auto>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Empresa</th>";
        echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
        echo "<th>Serviço</th>";
        echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
        echo "<th>Pagamento</th>";
        echo "<th>Distrito</th>";
        echo "<th>Ações</th>";
        echo "<th>Avaliar</th>";
        echo "<th>Total</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['id_oferta']."</td>";
        echo "<td>autor:".$produto['user_of'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['categ'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['titulo'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['descricao'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['valor'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['local'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=aceita.php?id=".$produto['id'].">Aceitar</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a  href=fav.php?id=".$produto['id']."><img src='img/fav.png' height='24' width='24'></a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['fav'] . "</td>";










        echo "</tr>";

    }
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: antes do ORDER BY.. adicione outro INNER JOIN ofertas_pro...

Comment: Você pode fazer quantos JOIN achar necessário

Comment: Não estou a conseguir... Eu tenho 3 tabelas Ofertas, Ofertas_pro e Favoritos eu quero selecionar os campos da ofertas, e ofertas pro e ir na tabela favoritos buscar pelo  id da ofertas e ofertas_pro

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e especifique o que você quer obter das três tabelas.

Comment: Sobre o deu para entender, havia entendido da primeira.

Comment: Coloque o script das tabelas e o resultado que voce quer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT ofertas.id, ofertas.titulo, ofertas.descricao,  ofertas.valor, ofertas.user_of, ofertas.categ, ofertas.local, ofertas.fav, favoritos.id_oferta

FROM ofertas
INNER JOIN favoritos
ON ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta
ORDER BY favoritos.id_user='$login_session'";
```

Na tabela dos favoritos eu tenho id, id_user, id_oferta(seja ela oferta simples ou oferta_pro)

então..

```
SELECT 
favoritos.id,

ofertas.titulo,
ofertas.descricao,  
ofertas.valor, 
ofertas.user_of, 
ofertas.categ, 
ofertas.local, 
ofertas.fav, 
favoritos.id_oferta

ofertas_pro.titulo, 
ofertas_pro.descricao,  
ofertas_pro.valor, 
ofertas_pro.user_of, 
ofertas_pro.categ, 
ofertas_pro.local, 
ofertas_pro.fav, 

FROM favoritos 
LEFT JOIN ofertas ON (ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta) 
LEFT JOIN ofertas_pro ON (ofertas_pro.id=favoritos.id_oferta)
```

Se isso representar +/- o que você precisa, sugiro reestruturar suas tabelas, afinal ofertas_pro é uma oferta, mas certamente com alguma diferença, na tabela ofertas_pro voce deveria colocar o id_oferta e o que é diferente! ficaria assim a query

```
SELECT 
favoritos.id,

ofertas.titulo,
ofertas.descricao,  
ofertas.valor, 
ofertas.user_of, 
ofertas.categ, 
ofertas.local, 
ofertas.fav, 

favoritos.id_oferta

ofertas_pro.informacao1_pro
ofertas_pro.informacao1_pro

FROM ofertas 
INNER JOIN ofertas_pro ON (ofertas.id=ofertas_pro.id_oferta) 
INNER JOIN favoritos ON (ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta) 
ORDER BY favoritos.id_user='$login_session'
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!! Abraço!

Comment: David ajuda David :)

Answer (score 0):

Faça algo assim:

```
SELECT o.id, o.titulo, p.outroCampo, f.qualquerCampo
FROM ofertas AS o, ofertas_pro AS p, favoritos AS f
WHERE o.id = f.id_oferta
ORDER BY f.id_user;
```

É possível usar o INNER JOIN e ON também várias vezes, mas particularmente eu prefiro este modo (não sei se é mais eficiente ou não).